# Combining multiple pivot tables horizontally and vertically in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, append, pivot-table

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOcGz.png)

and I need to get this output:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIWSk.png)

Is using pivot tables (in python pandas) first for each Q, then appending over each column, and then merging the resulting dataframes for reach Q the best way to do it? Any suggestion on how to do that to get the right format?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["gender",'region'], value_vars=['q1','q2'], value_name='ques')
df2 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars='ques', value_vars=["gender",'region'], value_name='col')
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df2,index='ques',columns=['col'], aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
print(df3)

    col                             EE   LA   WE female male
ques                                                         
1'Agree + strongly agree            5.0  1.0  4.0    6.0  4.0
2'neither agree nor disagree        0.0  0.0  1.0    1.0  0.0
3'disagree + strongly disagree      0.0  3.0  0.0    3.0  0.0
no                                  5.0  3.0  4.0    8.0  4.0
yes                                 0.0  1.0  1.0    2.0  0.0
```